# Make [dynamics-finops] a synonym of [dynamics-365-operations]?

Tags: support, synonym-request

Could a moderator make [dynamics-finops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-finops) (11 questions) a synonym of [dynamics-365-operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-365-operations) (174 questions)?

The synonym cannot be suggested using the normal mechanism, because you get the error message:

> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

After raising a moderator flag on one of the questions, I was redirected to create this request here along with a justification, but for someone who is familiar with the Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations product, it is obvious that the tags mean the same thing.

**Edit**

It was suggested in the comments to do a retag. As far as I understand it, retagging means editing each question and replacing a tag with another tag. While this is certainly possible to do for 11 questions, it would not prevent future questions with this tag, correct? If yes, I'm not sure what the advantage of a manual retagging is over the creation of a synonym. Is there some guidance on when to do a retagging instead of creating a synonym?

Comment: Wouldn't a retag be enough?

Comment: you are redirected to meta because tag synonym creation is a community-driven process. Yes, creating synonyms is hard because the requirements are unnecessarily harsh, thus the usual advice is to ask on Meta as you get the exposure needed to finalize to see the request through. If there is no active harm done, there is no need to bother already very busy moderators with what community can handle by themselves.

Comment: @OlegValter "*what community can handle by themselves*" I mean, in this case, there's *literally* a system block in place against the community creating this synonym, so I'm not sure that fully applies in this specific case :P

Comment: Why "dynamic-365-operations" trips as a "version specific synonym", though, is a different issue.

Comment: @zcoop98 the middle sentence of the question completely blinked out of existence for me :) Wow. Btw, the issue seems to be dating back to 2012 (!) See [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157869/786798), for example

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question with my thoughts on this.

Comment: "it would not prevent future questions with this tag, correct?" yes, it would. Since you need 3k reputation to create tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Braiam in the comments, a retagging of the questions seems to be the preferred solution in this case.

My assumption that this would not prevent future questions with the [dynamics-finops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-finops) was not correct. Since currently no question with that tag exists anymore, it should be deleted automatically after some time. After that, only users with a certain amount of reputation (1.500 when this answer was written) could recreate the tag.